# attendance system database in codepen. database?

Tags: html, database, codepen

I manage to make my attendance system a website in codepen by exporting it with help but I need to save all the data like names, all the checks, etc. I have a hard time understanding what a database is, is the database like save and load? I've searched how to create database in codepen and the result is using MySQL and PHP but it's too complicated. can I make a database in codepen or the database can only be made in visual studio code? any notes that explain the database for begginers or source code that is almost identical to my attendance system with the database.

[image: My attendance studio]

Comment: Why not use a proper development system?

Comment: @Nico Haase what's that?